# PostgreSQL Sum Between Table

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables each with a common field. I would like to calculate a SUM for each row in table 3 from a column in table 1 and a column on table 2. The SUM however must be based on the matching ID field.

So far I have:

```
INSERT INTO table_3.cost_label
SELECT table_1.col_2 + table_2.col_2
FROM table_1, table_2;

Table 1
ID   Value
1     10
2     20
3     30

Table 2
ID   Value
1     20
2     40
3     60

Table 3-Final Output
ID   Value
1     30
2     60
3     90
```

Is there a way to base this on a common matching field?

Comment: if I get you right - it is already on the matching field - no?

Comment: No its simple calculating the sum between table 1 and table 2 and placing it in table 3 below the current records.

Comment: please post some sample data and wanted result

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a join condition. You can do it the non-explicit way:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (ID, cost_label)
SELECT
  table_1.ID,
  table_1.col_2 + table_2.col_2
FROM
  table_1,
  table_2
WHERE
  table_1.ID = table_2.ID;
```

Or the explicit way:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (ID, cost_label)
SELECT
  table_1.ID,
  table_1.col_2 + table_2.col_2
FROM
  table_1
  JOIN table_2 ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @jcaron. I tried your approach yet the output of sum between table 1 and table 2 still does not join to the corresponding ID in table 3

Comment: You said you wanted to add new rows? What do you actually want to do? Update data in existing rows?

Comment: Yes, the rows in table 3 must be updated with the output of the sum between table 1 and table 2. The join to table 3 must be related to the common ID field though. My latest approach was an INNER JOIN, but still not having success.